# Ramda: Parameters in nested loops

Tags: ramda.js

I am trying to rewrite Javascript code point-free with Ramda. This is as far as I got:

```
R.reject((something: Something) =>
  R.any(
    R.allPass([R.eqProps('property1', something),
               R.propEq('property2', otherObject)]),
    list1),
  list2 ?? [])
```

My next step is to get rid of the `something` variable (before I take care of other variables). How can I achieve that?

Here is the original code:

```
list2?.filter((something: Something) =>
  list1.every(item =>
    (item.property1 !== something.property1) || (item.property2 !== otherObject))
  )
)
```

Comment: Please add the original code that you are rewriting.

Comment: It feels a little odd trying to remove that point when you still include the free variables `otherObject`, `list1` and `list2`.  As OriDrori said, we need more context.

Comment: Where is `otherObject` coming from?

Comment: I added the original code above. I wanted to take care of the other variables in a later step (and I hope the answer to this question will help me with that, too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one conversion:

```js
const otherObject = 42
const list1 = [{property1: 12, property2: 40}, {property1: 13, property2: 41}, {property1: 14, property2: 42}, {property1: 15, property2: 40}, {property1: 12, property2: 41}, {property1: 13, property2: 42}, {property1: 14, property2: 40}, {property1: 15, property2: 41}, {property1: 12, property2: 42}, {property1: 13, property2: 40}, {property1: 14, property2: 41}, {property1: 15, property2: 42}]
const list2 = [{property1: 10, foo: 'a'}, {property1: 11, foo: 'b'}, {property1: 12, foo: 'c'}, {property1: 13, foo: 'd'}, {property1: 14, foo: 'e'}, {property1: 15, foo: 'f'}, {property1: 16, foo: 'g'}]

const foo = list2 =>
  list2 .filter (
    (something) => list1 .every (
      item => (item.property1 !== something.property1) || (item.property2 !== otherObject)
    )
  )

const bar = filter (pipe (
  complement (eqProps ('property1')),
  either (complement (propEq ('property2', otherObject))),
  all (__, list1)
)) 

console .log ('vanilla:', foo (list2))
console .log ('ramda:',   bar (list2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {filter, pipe, complement, eqProps, either, propEq, all, __} = R</script>
```

As discussed in the comments, this is far from points-free, though.  And it will likely get uglier when you try to capture the `list1` and `otherObject` free variables.

There's a good question as to *why* you want to conver this to Ramda.  I'm one of the founders of Ramda and a big fan, but it's meant to be something to use when it helps, not a target to aim for.

---

Getting there was not a clean process for me.  I went at this in a roundabout way.  If you're interested in the gory details, you can see my many steps here:

```js
const otherObject = 42
const list1 = [{property1: 12, property2: 40}, {property1: 13, property2: 41}, {property1: 14, property2: 42}, {property1: 15, property2: 40}, {property1: 12, property2: 41}, {property1: 13, property2: 42}, {property1: 14, property2: 40}, {property1: 15, property2: 41}, {property1: 12, property2: 42}, {property1: 13, property2: 40}, {property1: 14, property2: 41}, {property1: 15, property2: 42}]
const list2 = [{property1: 10, foo: 'a'}, {property1: 11, foo: 'b'}, {property1: 12, foo: 'c'}, {property1: 13, foo: 'd'}, {property1: 14, foo: 'e'}, {property1: 15, foo: 'f'}, {property1: 16, foo: 'g'}]


console .log (
  list2 .filter (
    (something) => list1 .every (
      item => (item.property1 !== something.property1) || (item.property2 !== otherObject)
    )
  )
)


console .log (
  list2 .filter (
    (something) => list1 .every (
      anyPass ([
        complement (eqProps ('property1', something)),  
        complement (propEq ('property2', otherObject))
      ])
    )
  )
)

console .log (
  list2 .filter (
    (something) => 
      pipe (
        complement (eqProps ('property1')),
        of,
        concat ([complement (propEq ('property2', otherObject))]),
        anyPass,
        flip (all) (list1)
      ) (something)
  )
)


console .log (
  filter (
    (something) => 
      pipe (
        complement (eqProps ('property1')),
        of,
        concat ([complement (propEq ('property2', otherObject))]),
        anyPass,
        flip (all) (list1)
      ) (something),
    list2
  )
)

console .log (
  filter (pipe (
    complement (eqProps ('property1')),
    of,
    concat ([complement (propEq ('property2', otherObject))]),
    anyPass,
    flip (all) (list1)
  ), list2)
)

console .log (
  filter (pipe (
    complement (eqProps ('property1')),
    flip (append) ([complement (propEq ('property2', otherObject))]),
    anyPass,
    flip (all) (list1)
  )) (list2)
)

console .log ( 
  filter (pipe (
    complement (eqProps ('property1')),
    flip (append) ([complement (propEq ('property2', otherObject))]),
    anyPass,
    flip (all) (list1)
  )) (list2)
)

console .log (
  filter (pipe (
    complement (eqProps ('property1')),
    either (complement (propEq ('property2', otherObject))),
    all (__, list1)
  )) (list2) 
)
```

By logging the results of each step, I could ensure that I wasn't breaking things along the way.  And running this in [the REPL](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.27.0#?console%20.clear%20%28%29%0A%0Aconst%20otherObject%20%3D%2042%0Aconst%20list1%20%3D%20%5B%7Bproperty1%3A%2012%2C%20property2%3A%2040%7D%2C%20%7Bproperty1%3A%2013%2C%20property2%3A%2041%7D%2C%20%7Bproperty1%3A%2014%2C%20property2%3A%2042%7D%2C%20%7Bproperty1%3A%2015%2C%20property2%3A%2040%7D%2C%20%7Bproperty1%3A%2012%2C%20property2%3A%2041%7D%2C%20%7Bproperty1%3A%2013%2C%20property2%3A%2042%7D%2C%20%7Bproperty1%3A%2014%2C%20property2%3A%2040%7D%2C%20%7Bproperty1%3A%2015%2C%20property2%3A%2041%7D%2C%20%7Bproperty1%3A%2012%2C%20property2%3A%2042%7D%2C%20%7Bproperty1%3A%2013%2C%20property2%3A%2040%7D%2C%20%7Bproperty1%3A%2014%2C%20property2%3A%2041%7D%2C%20%7Bproperty1%3A%2015%2C%20property2%3A%2042%7D%5D%0Aconst%20list2%20%3D%20%5B%7Bproperty1%3A%2010%2C%20foo%3A%20%27a%27%7D%2C%20%7Bproperty1%3A%2011%2C%20foo%3A%20%27b%27%7D%2C%20%7Bproperty1%3A%2012%2C%20foo%3A%20%27c%27%7D%2C%20%7Bproperty1%3A%2013%2C%20foo%3A%20%27d%27%7D%2C%20%7Bproperty1%3A%2014%2C%20foo%3A%20%27e%27%7D%2C%20%7Bproperty1%3A%2015%2C%20foo%3A%20%27f%27%7D%2C%20%7Bproperty1%3A%2016%2C%20foo%3A%20%27g%27%7D%5D%0A%0A%0Aconsole%20.log%20%28%0A%20%20list2%20.filter%20%28%0A%20%20%20%20%28something%29%20%3D%3E%20list1%20.every%20%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20item%20%3D%3E%20%28item.property1%20%21%3D%3D%20something.property1%29%20%7C%7C%20%28item.property2%20%21%3D%3D%20otherObject%29%0A%20%20%20%20%29%0A%20%20%29%0A%29%0A%0Aconsole%20.log%20%28%0A%20%20list2%20.filter%20%28%0A%20%20%20%20%28something%29%20%3D%3E%20list1%20.every%20%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20anyPass%20%28%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20complement%20%28eqProps%20%28%27property1%27%2C%20something%29%29%2C%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20complement%20%28propEq%20%28%27property2%27%2C%20otherObject%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%29%0A%20%20%20%20%29%0A%20%20%29%0A%29%0A%0Aconsole%20.log%20%28%0A%20%20list2%20.filter%20%28%0A%20%20%20%20%28something%29%20%3D%3E%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20pipe%20%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20complement%20%28eqProps%20%28%27property1%27%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20of%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20concat%20%28%5Bcomplement%20%28propEq%20%28%27property2%27%2C%20otherObject%29%29%5D%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20anyPass%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20flip%20%28all%29%20%28list1%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%20%28something%29%0A%20%20%29%0A%29%0A%0Aconsole%20.log%20%28%0A%20%20filter%20%28%0A%20%20%20%20%28something%29%20%3D%3E%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20pipe%20%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20complement%20%28eqProps%20%28%27property1%27%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20of%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20concat%20%28%5Bcomplement%20%28propEq%20%28%27property2%27%2C%20otherObject%29%29%5D%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20anyPass%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20flip%20%28all%29%20%28list1%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%20%28something%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20list2%0A%20%20%29%0A%29%0A%0Aconsole%20.log%20%28%0A%20%20filter%20%28pipe%20%28%0A%20%20%20%20complement%20%28eqProps%20%28%27property1%27%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20of%2C%0A%20%20%20%20concat%20%28%5Bcomplement%20%28propEq%20%28%27property2%27%2C%20otherObject%29%29%5D%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20anyPass%2C%0A%20%20%20%20flip%20%28all%29%20%28list1%29%0A%20%20%29%2C%20list2%29%0A%29%0A%0Aconsole%20.log%20%28%0A%20%20filter%20%28pipe%20%28%0A%20%20%20%20complement%20%28eqProps%20%28%27property1%27%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20flip%20%28append%29%20%28%5Bcomplement%20%28propEq%20%28%27property2%27%2C%20otherObject%29%29%5D%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20anyPass%2C%0A%20%20%20%20flip%20%28all%29%20%28list1%29%0A%20%20%29%29%20%28list2%29%0A%29%0A%0Aconsole%20.log%20%28%20%0A%20%20filter%20%28pipe%20%28%0A%20%20%20%20complement%20%28eqProps%20%28%27property1%27%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20flip%20%28append%29%20%28%5Bcomplement%20%28propEq%20%28%27property2%27%2C%20otherObject%29%29%5D%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20anyPass%2C%0A%20%20%20%20flip%20%28all%29%20%28list1%29%0A%20%20%29%29%20%28list2%29%0A%29%0A%0Aconsole%20.log%20%28%0A%20%20filter%20%28pipe%20%28%0A%20%20%20%20complement%20%28eqProps%20%28%27property1%27%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20either%20%28complement%20%28propEq%20%28%27property2%27%2C%20otherObject%29%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20all%20%28__%2C%20list1%29%0A%20%20%29%29%20%28list2%29%20%0A%29%0A%0A), I could see it in real time.

But you can see that it was a roundabout process that got me to that answer.  `allPass` was a wrong turn, when `either` would have been cleaner.  In the end we got to something fairly reasonable, modulo the free variables.  But the process was anything but smooth.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I agree that not everything needs to be made pointless, I just took this as an excercise when learning Ramda, when I wondered how to reach this inner variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is a best-effort (in the absence of runnable code) at making your inner lambda pointfree.

```js
list2?.filter((something: Something) =>
  R.all(
    R.pipe(
      R.repeat(1),
      R.ap([prop('property1'), R.prop('property2')]),
      R.zipWith(R.flip(R.applyTo), R.map(R.equals, [something.property1, otherObject])),
      R.reduce(R.and, true),
      R.not
    ),
    list1
  )
)
```

I really wouldn't bother trying to make the outer lambda pointfree (I just don't think it'll be readable)

Comment: Thank you for this answer! It still contains the point (`something`) I wanted to get rid of, though. However, I am still at the beginning of my Ramda knowledge and it is great to see how others solve such an issue.